# How to create mysql user and database using php script?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to Create `mysql` user and database using `php` script

how to create `mysql` user using `mysql_query()`

```
<?php
    mysql_query("CREATE USER 'demodemodemo'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'jayul321';");
?>
```

this is not working..

Comment: That would work if the connected user has privileges to grant permissions to the new user. You need to check for errors `mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error());`  Of course, use caution when creating users from application code. It is an exotic use case to be creating database users in an application unless the application is a database management client

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP script to create MySQL database, add user and grant privileges.

```
## make sure you connect first to mysql with a super user (ex: root)
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password');

$dbName = 'database_name'; // new database name
$dbUser = 'db_user';       // new user name
$dbPass = 'db_pass';       // new user password

$queries = array(
    "CREATE DATABASE `$dbName` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci",
    "CREATE USER '$dbUser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '$dbPass'",
    "GRANT USAGE ON * . * TO '$dbUser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '$dbPass' WITH MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 0",
    "GRANT SELECT , INSERT , UPDATE, DELETE ON `$dbName` . * TO '$dbUser'@'localhost'",
    "FLUSH PRIVILEGES"
);

foreach($queries as $query) {
    echo 'Executing query: "'.htmlentities($query).'" ... ';
    $rs = mysql_query($query);
    echo ($rs ? 'OK' : 'FAIL') . '<br/><br/>';
}
```

Comment: what 0 represent on MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 0

Comment: 0 means unlimited: "To remove a limit, set its value to zero" Source: MySQL manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-resources.html